# Finding a Taylor's series from f(x) = $x^{3/2}$ at x = 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

My function is $x^{3/2}$ and I need to find the Taylor series around 1.

I calculated the first 5 derivatives. And I calculated the values of those results at 1.

The derivatives were: $\frac{3x^2}{2x^{3/2}}$ ; $\frac{3}{4x^{1/2}}$ ; $-\frac{3}{8 x  x^{1/2}}$ ; $\frac{9}{16x^2 x^{1/2}}$ ; $-\frac{45}{32x^3 x^{1/2}}$

With x=1 I got (f(1) = 1) the following values: 3/2, 3/4, -3/8, 9/16, -45/32

This got me the following Taylor's series:

$1 + \frac{3(x-1)}{2} + \frac{3(x-1)^2}{8} - \frac{1(x-1)^3}{16} + \frac{3(x-1)^4}{128} - \frac{3(x-1)^5}{256}$ + ...

Now in order to solve it I have to find a way to get it to the 'overall generic' form (no idea what it's called in English), so I can type it in the summation notation. Then I can find the way to find the period where it converges (or just prove that the entire thing converges).

The problem is that I have no idea how to create the "An" of that sequence. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this "general form" you want for the coefficients must be related with the binomial coefficient.

Comment: calculus newbies might have problems to accept that there is a binomial coefficient, $n$ over $k$, version with non-integral $n$.

Comment: Do you mean canonical form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I hope this helps, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

I would start with that. This is a way for defining the generic power function
in introductory calculus courses.

And here is the relevant integer sequence for the numerators
https://oeis.org/A161200

Comment: so you can now try to find a generic form for the $k$th derivative of $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ and prove that via induction.

Comment: Hmm, okay, so I looked at the wikipedia thing. So basically I tried to construct a similar thing: I'm having some trouble with it.

Most of my constructed taylor's series is similar enough. My alfa x = 3 (x-1)/2. That means my alfa would be 3/2 and I could substitute (x-1) with y.

That creates (1+x)^(3/2). How do I get (x-1) like in your integer sequence?

Comment: use the wikipedia formula for expanding $(1+(x-1))^{3/2}$ then compare the coefficients of $(x-1)^k$ with the coefficients when writing down the usual taylor expansion at $x_0=1$. If you get the idea you will understand how to find the $k$th derivative. You might try to differentiate $x^{20}$ ten times.

Comment: Okay. I wrote wikipedia's thing out. I think it's exactly the same as mine.

$(1+(x-1))^{3/2}$ comes out to the same thing. Now wikipedia tells me that |x| < 1 converges. That would be |x-1| for me. But why does WolframAlpha tell me that my series converges |1-x| ?

Answer (score 3):

If you write $y=x-1$, then $$x^\frac{3}{2}=(1+(x-1))^\frac{3}{2}$$. 
Consider how you would do the series if $3/2$ were replaced by an integer. Newton's binomial theorem shows that the coefficients in the infinite series are in fact created by the same formula that creates binomial coefficients in the integer case.

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution. Thank you.